# UITextView keep scrolling after every new line is inserted, so the lines are invisible (iPhone OS)

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, uitextview

I have UITextView and a situation that is problematic.
I write line of text in the UITextView, and then press return for new line.
What happen is, the line that i entered is moving up so i can't see it, and i am able to continue writing.
This is bad behavior for me, because i need the line to stay, and only move up when i reach the bottom of the UITextView.

- I've read other similar posts but they wasn't helpfull.

Is someone familiar with this thing?

Answer (score 0):

I had luck using this solution: [How to stop UITextView from scrolling up when entering it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178010/how-to-stop-uitextview-from-scrolling-up-when-entering-it/1864205#1864205)

However, I also found depending on the size of my UITextView, the insets needed to get it to scroll correctly varied and subclassing wasn't always necessary.  For instance, for a text view of height 40 (very small for a UITextView), I did the following:

```
textView_ = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40)];
textView_.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-6, -8, 0, 0);
```