# UITextView auto scrolling

Tags: uitableview, uitextview, autoscroll

I've put my UITextView into UITableViewCell but i can't understand - why scroll always goes to the top?..I can't type properly because i don't see where am i type..

[textView scrollRangeToVisible:NSMakeRange([textView.text length]-1, 1)];
textView.selectedRange = NSMakeRange(textView.text.length - 1, 0);
This both solution don't work in my case...

Answer (score 0):

It's an Apple UI automatic behavior if the UITextView is too small.
Here is a solution : [How to stop UITextView from scrolling up when entering it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178010/how-to-stop-uitextview-from-scrolling-up-when-entering-it#answer-1864205)