# iPhone: Stop UIScrollView from auto scrolling when UITextView text is changed

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextview

Hi I have several UITextView's inside a UIScrollView. After a certain action occurs, I change the text of all the UITextView's using [info setText:@"blahblah"], then I modify each TextView's frame so that all the text is viewable. Then I change the content size of the UIScrollView so that it fits all the text.

The problem is that after I do this it scrolls when I would like for it to stay at the top of the screen. [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,0) animated:YES]; doesn't seem to keep the scrollView at the top.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [scrollRectToVisible:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html) to keep the scrollview at the top

Answer (score 0):

I used another view in mine, eg: UIWebView, and covered it up with a button.
That only works for non-editable.

Try:
[How to stop UITextView from scrolling up when entering it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178010/how-to-stop-uitextview-from-scrolling-up-when-entering-it/1864205#1864205)

Answer (score -1):

`[scrollView setScrollsToTop:NO];` maybe?

Comment: `setScrollsToTop:NO` doesn't effect the `UITextView` scrolling that's going on here, plus `setScrollsToTop:NO` would impact other functionality, like tapping the caption bar to scroll to top.