# UITextField canBecomeFirstResponder returns NO

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiresponder

In the method `-(void)registerUser` I present a modal view with 2 UITextFields and a Ok Button.

After filling the UITextFields and pressing the Ok Button I call the delegate method `-(void)AEMUserRegistrationVCUserName:(NSString *)un password:(NSString *)pw` where I verify the data connecting to a server.

When the answer arrives in `-(void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response` If the data is wrong I try to set focus on the UITextfield with `self.userRegistrationVC.userName becomeFirstResponder]`but it does not get the focus.

I have checked `[self.userRegistrationVC.userName canBecomeFirstResponder]` and it returns NO, which on the other hand is what the docs say it is returned by default.

My code is here as a reference:

Note:

`self.userName`and `selfPassword`are NSStrings.
`self.userRegistrationVC`is a UIViewController.
`self.userRegistrationVC.userName`and `self.userRegistrationVC.password`are UITextfields.

```
-(void)registerUser
{
    //Recuperar el nombre de usuario
    self.userName = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:kNombreUsuario];
    if (!self.userName) {
        //No hay nombre de usuario, el usuario nunca ha registrado la aplicación.
        if (!self.userRegistrationVC) {
            //Solicitar datos de registro
            self.userRegistrationVC = [[AEMUserRegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AEMUserRegistrationViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        self.userRegistrationVC.delegate = self;
        [self.viewControllerToPresentModalView presentModalViewController:self.userRegistrationVC animated:YES];
        return;
    }


    //Recuperar la contraseña
    NSError *error;
    self.password = [SFHFKeychainUtils getPasswordForUsername:self.userName andServiceName:kServiceName error:&error];
    if (!self.password) {
        //No hay contraseña. La contraseña se ha perdido.
        if (!self.userRegistrationVC) {
            //Solicitar datos de registro
            self.userRegistrationVC = [[AEMUserRegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AEMUserRegistrationViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        self.userRegistrationVC.delegate = self;
        [self.viewControllerToPresentModalView presentModalViewController:self.userRegistrationVC animated:YES];
        return;
    }

    //Los datos del usuario existen
    //Verificar el registro
    [self.client get:kConfirmUsuario
         queryParams:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.userName, self.password, nil] 
                                                 forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kNombreUsuario, kPassword, nil]]
                                                delegate:self];
}

-(void)AEMUserRegistrationVCUserName:(NSString *)un password:(NSString *)pw
{
    //El usuario ha introducido datos de registro
    //Realizar el registro
    self.userName = un;
    self.password = pw;
    [self.client get:kCreateUsuario 
         queryParams:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.userName, self.password, nil]
                                                 forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:kNombreUsuario, kPassword, nil]]
            delegate:self];

    //No hacer dismiss ahora esperar a verificar el registro
}


-(void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response
{
    //Puede responder a createUsuario o a confirmUsuario
    //En ambos casos el error impide registrar al usuario y ejecutar el programa
    BOOL isRequestCreateUser;
    NSRange aRange = [request.resourcePath rangeOfString:kCreateUsuario];
    if (aRange.location != NSNotFound) { 
        //The request was to create a user
        isRequestCreateUser = YES;
    } else {
        //The request was to check a user
        isRequestCreateUser = NO;
    }


    if (response.isConflict) {
        //Error
        [self.userRegistrationVC.userNameError setHidden:NO];
        if ([self.userRegistrationVC.password canResignFirstResponder]) {
            NSLog(@"SI"); //This return NO
        }
        if ([self.userRegistrationVC canBecomeFirstResponder]) {
            NSLog(@"SI"); //This returns NO           
        }
        [self.userRegistrationVC.userName becomeFirstResponder]; 
    }

    if (response.isServerError) {
        //Error
        [self.userRegistrationVC.userNameError setHidden:NO];
        [self.userRegistrationVC.userName becomeFirstResponder];                
    }



    if (response.isOK) {
        //Success

        //Retirar la pantalla de registro de usuario
        [self.viewControllerToPresentModalView dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        //Si la peticion fue crear un usuario
        if (isRequestCreateUser) {
            //Guardar el nombre de usuario en las preferencias del usuario
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:self.userName forKey:kNombreUsuario];           
            //Guardar la contraseña en KeyChain
             [SFHFKeychainUtils storeUsername:self.userName andPassword:self.password forServiceName:kServiceName updateExisting:YES error:nil];
        }

        [self.delegate AEMUserRegistrationSucess];
    }    
}
```

The sequence of calls will be:

- -(void)registerUser
- -(void)AEMUserRegistrationVCUserName:(NSString *)un password:(NSString *)pw
- -(void)request:(RKRequest *)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse *)response

Reading the Forum many questions are answered with [UITextField becomeFirstResponder] as a solution, so maybe I'm missing something important, and I cannot make it work.

The docs say you can override canBecomeFirstResponder to return YES, but how can I override a UITextField method? Is this what needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Try a UITextView. The pain of dealing with [iPhone: Stop UIScrollView from auto scrolling when UITextView text is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139876/iphone-stop-uiscrollview-from-auto-scrolling-when-uitextview-text-is-changed) can become your fruit. It does the exact opposite, no matter what... annoying but maybe viable if you limit the input via delegate callbacks